# Как передать данные

Tags: angular

Подскажите как можно передать в ангуляре данные ввода из инпута лежащего в дочернем компоненте в родительский компонент?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передача данных от дочернего компонента к родительскому называется "события" или "реакции на события". Событие содаётся при помощи `@Output` и `EventEmitter` в дочернем компоненте, подписка на событие происходит в родительском компоненте.

```
// child.ts
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  ...
})
export class ChildComponent {

  // ...

  // Создаём EventEmitter, который будет производить событие change у компонента
  // вместо change можно дать любое имя событию. В этом примере мы передаём число
  // но можно передавать любые данные
  @Output()
  change: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  // ...

  // Где-то в коде вызываем this.change.emit(данные); для того чтоб
  // передать данные наверх
  doChange() {
    this.change.emit(123);
  }
}


// parent.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <div class="app">
      Parent: {{ value }}
      <app-child
        <!--
          вот так мы получаем данные из дочернего компонента.
          данные события хранятся в специальной переменной $event.
        -->
        (change)="this.setValue($event)">
      </counter>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  value: number = 10;
  setValue(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

[Вот тут](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2) подробнее.

Comment: Из дочернего в родительский я понимаю как передавать, а вот именно значение из инпута, просто ввел пользователь несколько символов, как передать наверх?

Comment: <input (keyup)="onKey($event)">  в child компоненте в методе onKey() вызовите emit() своего события, что вам показали